# Emacs 24.5 , CUA mode. Not paste text in the minibuffer

Tags: emacs, copy-paste, yank, cua-mode

In Windows 7 / Emacs 24.5

1. Copy text e.g. `"example"` in the kill-ring
2. `M-x`
3. `C-y` (yank)
4. Success show text `"example"` in the minibuffer

But if turn on CUA-mode, the text `"example"` not yank (paste) by 'C-v' in the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUA mode makes `C-v` the yank/paste command.

If you start Emacs with :

```
emacs -Q
```

Then turn on CUA mode (`M-x cua-mode`) you'll see that `C-v` works as you expect.

Without knowing your setup it's difficult to be sure but it's likely you're using a package which modifies the behavior of `M-x` (E.g. smex, Ido,  ivy, etc.)

It's likely CUA mode won't really have anything to do with this problem. You can verify this by trying to do `C-y` to yank in the minibuffer too.

Packages which enhance `M-x` may provide a way to allow you to drop out temporarily, so you can yank text in-place.

### Update

From your comments we know you are using Helm, which overrides some bindings in the minibuffer, including `C-v` which is bound to page down.

Because bindings are applied at different mode (context) scopes, the minibuffer modemap (list of key bindings) will override anything that's applied at a more general context (such as cua mode)

To work around this you'd need to add a binding specifically for cua-paste in the affected mode map. It would need to be applied after Helm has loaded.

Comment: My apologies I misread your original key command as `C-y` (both would work BTW).  I've updated my answer for you.

Comment: my binding:

    (global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'helm-M-x)

Comment: That's why you have a problem, `Helm-M-x` overrides the cua-mode binding of `C-v`, and rebinds it to page down.  You'll have to use `C-y` or modify the helm key map.